# Cannot make the unit test work as expected

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I'm struggling to make the unit test for my event subscriber work as expected. So here is the test:

```
$user = new User();
$user->email = self::EMAIL;
$user->subscribed_to_mailing_list = TRUE;

$this->userRepository->expects($this->once())
    ->method('save')
    ->with($user);

$event = new UnsubscribedEmailsEvent([self::EMAIL]);//Here i get the webhook from 3-d parties about unsubscription

$this->subscriber->onUnsubscribedListReceived($event);

$this->assertFalse($user->subscribed_to_mailing_list);
```

and my test fails, because the user still have a `true` assigned, but must be the `false`.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you give `$user` as argument of  `UnsubscribedEmailsEvent`, it seems the event is not able to leverage `$user`.

Comment: @Lounis I getting user in the subscriber, and update them there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assertion fails, because user is not returned from repository in your subscriber service.
You should inject to your subscriber userRepository mock and then return user from it, for example:

```
    $this->userRepository
        ->expects($this->once())
        ->method('getById')
        ->willReturn($user);
```